# XCode 4 Relative #include paths in search?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, header-files

I'm trying to port over a project I initially wrote in Windows to OS X and am having some difficulty with the header search paths.

I've used user search paths to include by source folder `"project/src/core/"` 
Under core, I have, for example:
`"projects/src/core/sys/sys_sdl.h"`
which tries to include
`"projects/src/core/render/opengl_render.h"`
with the directive:

```
#include "render/opengl_render.h"
```

I've tried tons of different options, but I can't get seem to get Xcode to find the file unless I change it to `"../render/opengl_render.h"`

Is there something I'm missing here in the settings to get it to recognize relative paths to the header search paths?

Comment: And this relative solution fails if you have a header at another folder (let's say projects/gui/...) because than the relative path is wrong over there. :-(

Answer (score 6):

Did you try setting the User Header Search Path to `$SRCROOT/..`? $SRCROOT is the directory that contains the target's source files, so $SRCROOT/.. should be the directory above that, which I think is what you want.

A related question ([How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6910901/643383)) shows a useful command that makes it easy to see all the build settings and the variables they modify:

```
$ xcodebuild -project myProj.xcodeproj -target "myTarg" -showBuildSettings
```

Comment: How the heck would you know this, though? Why don't they just have a pop-up menu that has all the possible wildcards? And how's this different from doing $(PROJECT)

Comment: I think PROJECT is just the name of the project itself, whereas SRCROOT is the path to the target's source files. As for why there's not a popup, it's probably a combination of preserving flexibility (you need to be able to specify any path) and it not adding enough value to make it a priority. Also, see my edit above.