# Relative headers XCode 4

Tags: c++, ios, xcode4, include, relative-path

I've been trying to port my pThread classes over to iOS.  As such I have moved them all across to my XCode project into a subdirectory from the main files called "Threading".

However I can't compile.  In the pThreadThread.cpp, for example, it has a

```
 #include "Threading/pThreadThread.h"
```

and yet XCode returns me an error saying it can't find the header.  I'm assuming this is because it is looking from the directory that the header is currently in.  As such adding "../" on the front does seem to help, however its not a very good solution, IMO.

So I found this thread:

[XCode 4 Relative #include paths in search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643953/xcode-4-relative-include-paths-in-search)

But on trying the solution it doesn't seem to work.  First thing I noticed was that the actual source data was under $SRCROOT/ so I added that in (Firstly under User Header paths and then, because that didn't work, under normal header paths) and ... it still doesn't work.

Whats going on?  How can I get relative header including to actually work?

Edit: The command line looks like this

```
CompileC /Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/Objects-normal/i386/pthreadThread.o VoiceAnalyser/Threading/pthreadThread.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford Wave Research/VoiceAnalyser"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -iquote /Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/VoiceAnalyser-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/VoiceAnalyser-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/VoiceAnalyser-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/VoiceAnalyser-project-headers.hmap -iquote/Volumes/Dev -iquoteDisk/Development/Oxford -iquoteWave -iquoteResearch/VoiceAnalyser -I/Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/VoiceAnalyser-Prefix-dzvjbuvabxhsdtfseyyxyapbsuqv/VoiceAnalyser-Prefix.pch -c "/Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford Wave Research/VoiceAnalyser/VoiceAnalyser/Threading/pthreadThread.cpp" -o /Users/oscarforth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceAnalyser-baxcnwbmyjmkfncxfxoaltcqbrzr/Build/Intermediates/VoiceAnalyser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VoiceAnalyser.build/Objects-normal/i386/pthreadThread.o

In file included from /Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford Wave Research/VoiceAnalyser/VoiceAnalyser/Threading/pthreadThread.cpp:1:
/Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford Wave Research/VoiceAnalyser/VoiceAnalyser/Threading/../Threading/pthreadThread.h:44:10: fatal error: 'Threading/pThreadEvent.h' file not found [2]
 #include "Threading/pThreadEvent.h"
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What are you adding to the Header paths? The directory containing pThreadThread.h, or the directory containing the Threading directory? The latter is what you _should_ be including in the header paths.

Comment: @Ben Hocking: $SRCROOT/<Project name> which points to the directory that my Threading subdirectory is in.  Yet I still get the same build error.

Comment: Also note ... I have checked and double checked ... it is definitely pointing to the directory that the threading directory is a subdirectory of.

Comment: Post your build log - specifically the expanded command-line call for the failed build action. Almost certainly there's something wrong with your paths. Perhaps it needs to be recursive? Perhaps there's a stray space in an un-enquoted path?

Comment: @Joshua: Edited original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be very careful about how Xcode interprets path with spaces. In my case, my

```
-I/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/...
```

becomes

```
-I/Volumes/Macintosh -IHD/Users/...
```

check your paths in project settings like **Header Search Path** and add double quote to your path.

```
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/YOURLIBRARY"
```

instead of

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/YOURLIBRARY
```

This issue got me when I tried to load my project from non-boot volume

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this path:

> /Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford
>   Wave
>   Research/VoiceAnalyser/VoiceAnalyser/Threading/../Threading/pthreadThread.h

... is unintentional. Your header search path should resolve to:

> /Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford
>   Wave
>   Research/VoiceAnalyser/VoiceAnalyser/

... if you want to use the "Threading/whatever.h" subpath.

Comment: But where the hell is XCode getting that from?? The User Header search path is set to /Volumes/Dev Disk/Development/Oxford Wave Research/VoiceAnalyser/VoiceAnalyser/ ...

Comment: Double-click the value and post the actual setting (not what it resolves to visibly when the setting isn't being edited).

Comment: Hang on a sec - it says it's going up one and descending again because it's including in pthreadThread.cpp. The include should just be "pthreadThread.h" not "Threading/pthreadThread.h", since it's in the same folder.

Comment: I may be wrong but I could have sworn that on other platforms it works by working out the header path relative to the original file including the header.  Which is why I like to be explicit.  Certainly I've only ever had this problem with XCode 4 (XCode 3 was ok if you set everything as relative to the project).

Comment: A lot of people are having Xcode 4 problems. :-) It may very well be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory to the Header Search Path in the Build Settings of the project that includes it.