# importing project samples in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I had downloaded a sample source project to the downloads directory. But I could not find any documentation about how these sample project are imported in the Xcode ide so that i can build and run the code to have a quick look up. Is these downloaded sample project should be build and run by importing can be possible in Xcode. if yes then please please please have a nice method to do this.

Thanking you..

Answer (score 7):

Just double click on the **.xcodeproj** file.

[image]

Comment: lol... that is a very clear example!

Comment: "To be clear for newbies out there, you should be opening the `.xcworkspace` file, not the `.xcodeproj`." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the folder and then open the .xcodeproj file?

Comment: Thanks you very much. It looks like quite simple. Great

Answer (score 1):

You just have to double-click on the .xcodeproj file to launch the sample project with Xcode. Then choose the way you want to "execute" the application (for example, on the iPhone simulator). Finally, Build and Run.

If you have "Missing SDK", click on the project name and select the deployment target, then click on the "Build Settings" tab and change the Base SDK to Latest for example.

Enjoy ! :)