# Cocoapods Testflight

Tags: xcode, linker, testflight, cocoapods

Anybody have cocoapods working with an Ad Hoc configuration for Testflight?

I have the same problem as: [library not found for -lPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods) but that answer does not make any sense and the documentation is absurdly sparse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your project might be looking for the `libPods.a` file but can't find it. If you build the Pods project the file should be accessible.

Go to your target summary and look under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` if the `libPods.a` isn't there or is red (missing) try building the just the pods project.

Comment: How do you build the pods project?

Comment: @mkirk. The Pods project will build with your Source project.  Be sure to open the workspace file that CocoaPods generated, not the project file when working with your project.

Answer (score 0):

This might be solved by one of the answers on
[library not found for -lPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods)
but JIC it saves you some heartache trying to decide which of the 31 answers to choose, try this potentially straightforward solution.

1. Select the main project from the list (that appears in the project
   navigator when you open the .xcworkspace file).
2. Choose Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme.
3. Select the "Build" item in the left hand pane.
4. Check the box that says "Find Implicit Dependencies".
5. Clean and Rebuild.