# Trouble using CocoaPods in project

Tags: restkit, cocoapods

I'm new to IOS Development and I'm trying to Restkit via cocoapods using [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods) tutorial with no success. I'm getting the following error:

```
Ld /Users/noor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EZ-POINT-cltwbuksnzhbqpabqekhgkzqspjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EZ-POINT.app/EZ-POINT normal i386
    cd /Users/noor/Documents/Apps/EZ-POINT.BK
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/noor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EZ-POINT-cltwbuksnzhbqpabqekhgkzqspjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/noor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EZ-POINT-cltwbuksnzhbqpabqekhgkzqspjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/noor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EZ-POINT-cltwbuksnzhbqpabqekhgkzqspjw/Build/Intermediates/EZ-POINT.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EZ-POINT.build/Objects-normal/i386/EZ-POINT.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -o /Users/noor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EZ-POINT-cltwbuksnzhbqpabqekhgkzqspjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EZ-POINT.app/EZ-POINT

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems as though the "Pods" library is not in your library search path. Check the build settings of the target you are building and make sure the Pods library can be found by the library search path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open your project by `.xcworkspace` not by `.xproject` :-)

Besides, I find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods) might help you solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should read this, you need a workspace, not a project http://docs.cocoapods.org/guides/integrating_a_project.html