# RestKit CocoaPods Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, restkit

The projects is very simple, just a blank tabbed application with RestKit - no other code. For some reason I keep getting a linker error:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is my output from Terminal after I run pod install:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (1.3.3)
Using ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer (0.5.0)
Using RKValueTransformers (1.0.1)
Using RestKit (0.22.0)
Using SOCKit (1.1)
Using TransitionKit (2.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

And output for pod --version:

```
$  pod --version
0.29.0
```

I also know that normally with RestKit I should link in libRestKit.a, but it does not show up in my list.

Comment: Did you follow https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods ?

Comment: On the same note, did you follow the set up properly: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Since I'm new to cocoapods I didn't know I had to open the workspace file instead of the project file. Very easy :)

[library not found for -lPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods)