# ld: library not found for -lPods not found in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

hello I have download code from bit bucket when we open xcode project it show error like this...

diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

but after that I am using terminal then update or pod setup using these links

```
  http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods
```

using  these link we install pod and after that pods and .xcworkspace file generate In project folder when we open .xcworkspace file and build project then it will build successfully but when we open .xcodproj and build this it will show error

```
   ld: library not found for -lPods
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so I don't know how to add libpods.a library and run this app .

Comment: thats normal  , you should use the .xcworkspace  file ..

Answer (score 0):

When using Pods, the xcodeproj file is obsolete, you should use the xcodeworkspace from now. That's why you are getting the "not found" error for pods in the xcodeproj

Answer (score -2):

Try to open .xcworkspace file and in target -> Build Settings -> Library Search Path , write down below line, and run in simulator:

```
"Pods/build/Debug-iphonesimulator"
```