# CocoaPods with XCode 6.0.1 - How can I fix Pods Frameworks appearing in red?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, cocoapods

I have created a new project in Xcode 6.0.1 and created the following Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

I then ran `pod install`, and opened the xcworkspace in Xcode.  When I build the project, all the frameworks appear in red.  For example, under the Pods project, the Foundation.framework appears in red, and refers to a path on my computer that doesn't exist:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework
```

My question is: **How can I get the frameworks to appear in black in the navigator, and properly link my pods to my main project?**

[image: Xcode screenshot]

I have made a couple changes mentioned in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23385837/1649678):

1. Originally, the libpods.a Product appeared in red as well. I fixed that by changing the **Per-configuration Build Products Path** to `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)` after reading that someone else fixed their problem that way.
2. I have made sure my **Base SDK** is iOS 8.0 on all the targets I can find.
3. I have verified that my **Valid Architectures** are set to "arm64 armv7 armv7.1" for all the targets I can find.

Comment: For me adding $(inherited) in "Other Linker Tags" in build settings of your main project (tmpios) did the trick, still in red but links properly and runs well.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same strange problem, where the libraries where correctly recognized on one machine, but not on another - there they were also in red.

The solution was to add the `Pods` target to the building scheme ("Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme..." then add with + the Pods main target and put it in front of your main target.) 
Then `clean` and `build` the project.

Comment: No, that doesn't help at all.

Comment: For me, this was the solution. This is also an official troubleshooting solution on the cocoapods site: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

Comment: adding the Pods framework did not work for me, but adding the individual frameworks did.

Comment: After 4 hours of trying to figure out why it still isn't working, your answer provided the correct solution - thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, since these frameworks don't exist in the pod's project path. As I see in tmpios->Frameworks doesn't appear in any of the frameworks that are supposed to exist.
Choose your project,then Target->tmpios->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries and there add the frameworks you need.

If still you have a compile error and doesn't find libraries of pods then write your pod file in that way:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
link_with  ['tmpios', 'tmpiosTests']
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

Install pods, and at your project Target->tmpios->Build Setting->Other Linker Flags, add $(inherited).

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the issue for me.  Also, I am trying to make the Frameworks appear in black under the Pods project, rather than red.

Comment: I am also looking solution to this problem. :(

Comment: Also waiting for solution :( For now I ended with not using cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete all configs in the the Pods Group in xcode and run pod install again. This will regenerate the xcconfigs files. Then make sure they are set properly in the Project > Info > Configurations

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out I just need to run a pod update with

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.And resolved by changing the path of the 'red framework'.because the path shows 'SDK IOS9' before.So i set the framework location 'relative to SDK' and choose the right framework location manually.and it works temporarily.

[image]

I guess the reason is that i updated to Xcode 8,but my coacopods is still old version,so it set the location with IOS9 which cause this problem.