# not able to acess installed pods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project and want to add HanekeSwfit to it using cocoapods for the first time. I did everything as it said but I have this problem.

[image]

[image]

Pods.framework is showing red. Why is this? When I try to add HanekeSwift manually I have the same problem.

Comment: There are other posts on SO about this. For me, the pod works just fine, it is just showing as red. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246805/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-0-1-how-can-i-fix-pods-frameworks-appearing-in-red) is one other post about the pods showing as red.

Comment: I saw that one but it didn't solve my problem..

Comment: The actual problem is that when I try to Import HanekeSwift it says No such module 'HanekeSwift'

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't opening the file from `.xcworkspace`... I have been trying to solve this for almost 2 hours.

Comment: The cocoapods docs say to do that I believe. I went through the same issue recently. Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: @SinanSamet I'm guessing the problem has been solved. Please answer this question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't opening the `.xcworkspace` file which has to be used after installing cocoapod. All I had to do was to use this file and work from there.