# ld: library not found for -lPods-MyApp-pop after Installing by CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am getting the following error after installing the pop library using CocoaPods.

```
***ld: library not found for -lPods-MyApp-pop
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***
```

My Podfile looks like this

> hash Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
>
> hash platform :ios, '7.0'
>
> target 'MyApp' do pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
>
> end
>
> target 'MyAppTests' do
>
> end

This is my first project using CocoaPods, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the project, then open the the ".xcworkspace" file instead of your ".xcodeproj" file. I ran into the exact same issue you are running into and opening the ".xcworkspace" solved the problem and let me build and run my project.

[Article discussing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods?rq=1)