# ld: library not found for -lPods-Google-Maps-iOS-SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I install googlemap pod file that time i got an error and unable to solved this .. please help me

I am getting this error:

> ld: library not found for -lPods-Google-Maps-iOS-SDK clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: it occurring in various scenes, may be your file is missing , may be your other linker flags not available

Comment: what type of other linker flags i have to add?

Comment: try to add -all_load

Comment: not solved .. still got same error

Comment: This link may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods?rq=1

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: no.... still not solved

Answer (score 0):

This is the error because u didn't integerate sdk using podfile correctly so the sdk files are missing in your project

Use this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start it will help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow this link properly https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start
and make sure you have set YES in BUILD ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE ONLY in build settings (in target).