# Xcode library not found -lpods. Clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, cocoapods, linker-errors

I know it is a repeated question but I've tried the solutions available in Stack Overflow and noting helped me. I'm adding `MWPhotoBrowser` via pod and it is happening. Anything I add it results in the same error. Here are the logs:

```
Ld /Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Intermediates/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProj normal i386
    cd /Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -L/Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries/Flurry -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries/Vizury -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries/Helpshift -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries/Notiphi -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries/GoogleAnalyticsV3.12 -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/src/libraries/Localytics-iOS-3.5.0 -L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj -filelist /Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Intermediates/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProj.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Intermediates/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProj.swiftmodule -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Intermediates/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/MyProj.app.xcent -framework WebKit -lAdIdAccess -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -framework CoreTelephony -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreMotion -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -framework Crashlytics -framework MobileAppTracker -lVizuryEventLogger -framework AdSupport -framework iAd -framework MobileCoreServices -lNotifyManager -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Security -weak-lz -weak-lsqlite3.0 -lFlurry_5.0.0 -lLocalytics -weak_framework CoreText -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreData -framework MessageUI -framework AVFoundation -framework AddressBookUI -framework QuartzCore -lHelpshift -framework CFNetwork -framework MapKit -framework GooglePlus -framework FacebookSDK -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileDeepLinking -framework GoogleOpenSource -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Intermediates/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProj_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/vijaykas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fxonghiiueuyuoeclquaxlqzofjh/Build/Intermediates/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProj

Ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vijaykas/MyProj/source/2015/Test/cf_re_ios_app/MyProj/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [library not found for -lPods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods)

Comment: @JAL, there is no duplicate, I some how figured it out that, if we add $(inherited) in the "Other Linker Flags" This error is resolved however a new error is appearing that one of the added library is not available. Don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You must **open** `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` instead of `<YourProject>.xcodeproj`.

The `xcworkspace` contains your `project` and your `pods`.

You also can follow this steps:

- **Uninstall** the `App` from `Device` or `Simulator`.
- Make sure **close** all `Xcode` Projects. (`.xcworkspace` and `.xcproject`) (sometimes `.xcproject` still open)
- **Run** `pod install` and `pod update`
- **Open** the `.xcworkspace`
- **Clean** and **Build** your Project

After that you should be able to run normally.