# Unsolvable linker error when compiling app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I've been working on an app for some time now and it had been giving me trouble compiling on an iPhone. Recently, it stopped compiling even on the simulator. I've browsed stack overflow and other websites for answers but I can't seem to find anything that resolves the issue. Below is the error I'm getting.

I've restored an earlier version of the entire app to see if that fixed the problem but it didn't seem to make any difference. I'm still getting the same error.

Can anyone help?

```
    Ld /Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lynx.app/lynx normal x86_64
cd /Users/beauharper/Documents/Developer/lynx
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/beauharper/Documents/Developer/lynx/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -filelist /Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Intermediates/lynx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lynx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/lynx.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lBolts -lFBSDKCoreKit -lFBSDKLoginKit -lParse -lParseFacebookUtilsV4 -lParseTwitterUtils -lParseUI -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework ImageIO -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework UIKit -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Intermediates/lynx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lynx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/lynx.swiftmodule -lPods -lPods-lynx -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Intermediates/lynx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lynx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/lynx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/beauharper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lynx-gbjyyjvzcpeldyadlzddtokengts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lynx.app/lynx

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Just clean your Project & simulator or reset your simulator try it

Comment: @MayankPatel I reset the simulator but no change.

Comment: have you clean your project in Xcode ? goto Products -> Clean

Comment: try to delete derived data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6

Comment: @MayankPatel I cleaned the project as well

Comment: There is no error there, that's just the linker commandline and environment setup. What's the actual error?

Comment: @damian the code below says

    ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods

Comment: @damian I took a look at that question and tried all of the solutions provided but came up empty-handed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further review and fiddling, and after reviewing a similar question referenced by @damian, it seems that the solution was this:

I separated the app and the test targets in the Podfile by using

```
target :App do
…
end

target :AppTests do
…
end
```

This resulted in two new products libPods-App.a and libPods-AppTests.a, respectively and they made the previous product libPods.a obsolete. I had to remove this product from the Link Binary With Libraries Section of the Build Phases configuration of both targets.

Thanks for the input everyone!

Comment: Awesome. Good job hunting that one down.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your Derived Data folder, restarting Xcode and and running the project again. Go to `Window -> Projects` and navigate to your project. There should be mention of your derived data folder. Press `Delete`, restart Xcode and try building it again. See if that kicks it back into high gear again.

Comment: I deleted all derived data both through Xcode and through terminal and I'm still getting the same error.