# xcode: library not found -lBolts

Tags: ios, objective-c

> I am getting error for iBolts and i add it in my project using pod. Look at the error once.
>
> ```
> d: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/chetumac-007/Desktop/untitled folder/MamaBear-iOS-App/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos'
> ```
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/chetumac-007/Desktop/untitled folder/MamaBear-iOS-App/Pods/FlurrySDK/Flurry'
>   ld: library not found for -lBolts
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Just read this: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/index.html

Comment: thanks for your response sir. For which topic should i read now? because i need to remove this on urgent basis.

Comment: You just need to install CocaPods, and check if you're trying to build `*.xcworkspace` not `*.xcodeproj`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [library not found for -lPods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods)

Comment: @user28434 sir i already install CocaPods and open project from .xcworkspace. still i get this error

Comment: this link not help me sir i already done all things in my project

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I am running into the same problem and getting library not found for -lBolts along with these warnings.   App installs and runs on iOS device but getting this error when compiling for simulator.