# Linker Issue Xcode Cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Installed three pods but for some reason can't get it to work
I tried reinstalling, updating, deintegrating but nothing does it.
I get the following errors. Tried creating the folders manually but the Linker Error remains always

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Clima' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for Clima

pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'

end
```

[image: error]
[image: error2]

Comment: Can you right click to the error "Linker command..." and select "Reveal in log", and add screenshot into your question?

Comment: @V.Khambir all added and also the Podfile if that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [library not found for -lPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frameworks aren't being built. Just open `{Yourproject}.xcworkspace` generated after adding cocoapods instead of `{Yourproject}.xcodeproj` - that should help.

Comment: It was that easy ! Thanks ! first time using pods.. Pods always generate a new file to use instead of Xcode project ?