# Where does xcode resolve "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) to on my system?

Tags: xcode, build

When Compiling for iPhone Simulator with Xcode 4.2, if I place

> "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"

in

> Build Settings / Header search paths / Debug

and exit editing I can see it resolves to:

> "build/Debug-iphoneos"

Where should this be on my system? I have looked in:

```
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{Project Name}/Build
```

but I can't find a file called build that contains a folder called Debug-iphoneos.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project/36213785#36213785) you can get them as simply as adding `export` into a shell script used in the build phase. you might even already have a script used in your build phases, so you can just dump `export` at the end of the that scrip and then just search for `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` from Xcode's **Report Navigator**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On my system, compiling an OSX project, that resolves to an absolute path:

```
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /Users/andy/Source/MyProject/build/Debug
```

There are so many Xcode build variables that I keep a text file with a sample list of them which I got from executing a custom build script and viewing the output within the log tab.

If your code is going into the `Library` folder, then that is hidden under Lion.  You can unhide it  from the command line (`Terminal`) using:

```
$ cd ~
$ chflags nohidden Library
```

You should then be able to see its content.

Another tip: I have a `~/tmp` folder where I let temporary stuff accumulate and I have set my Xcode preferences to put `DerivedData` and `Archives` into that folder so I can:

- delete it now and again (I don't like temporary stuff accumulating where I cannot control it).
- see it for packaging pre-release Archived project to testers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually compiling for Simulator. I've amended the question.