# Xcode - How to move app out of sandbox with run script?

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, run-script

Basically from what I understand is that if my app wants to use serial communication via the dock connector (pins 12 / 13) the app has to live outside the app sandbox folder.  Now I don't want to have to `ssh` into my phone and copy `theAppFolder.app` to `/Applications/` everytime I click `Run` in Xcode (that would just be silly).

Now while doing some research I came across [this blog post](http://hcgilje.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/iphone-serial-communication/). Down in the comments, someone gives [the idea](http://hcgilje.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/iphone-serial-communication/#comment-5562) of what I am talking about in this question.

Now is his solution the best way to do what I am thinking of doing, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion of the xcode build phase? It sounds like a sensible plan to me

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I don't think that link will actually **run** your app from /Applications.  I think it just **installs** it there, as the last step in your build.  Do you need a solution that runs and debugs directly from Xcode?

Comment: @Nate yeah if I could still debug the app on the device, from within Xcode, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I use Xcode's build command with a post-build script to get my app on my jailbroken iOS device and also start it using a tool from Cydia (it *will* actually run the app from the `/Applications` directory). Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13707260/381233) for more info. The thing still missing is the ability to debug, but I've gotten used to using `NSLog` and tailing the syslog.

Comment: Wow, I forgot I asked this question.  I ended up creating a shell script that updates my repo, which I then install via cydia.  http://pastie.org/5644673

Comment: You could also use variables from Xcode (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6911421/381233) in your script (assuming it's called by Xcode) to make it more general to enable use on other projects without changing directory paths, etc.

Comment: hmm, haven't really thought of any other projects at the moment.