# Passing data for iOS Simulator to use at runtime

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

When I run an application in the simulator can I get an environment variable of the directory that the app was installed in? Here is where it's being installed currently for me but the iOS version and GUID (i.e.'112318C3-A508-482D-9A1D-0A55B3B16FDB') will change, I'd like to have it as a variable after build.

`/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/112318C3-A508-482D-9A1D-0A55B3B16FDB`

If there's no way to get that as an environment variable, can I just get the GUID that it's naming the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain a bit more of what you are trying to accomplish?

I'm not sure about environment variables containing that path, however you can add the following method in your application and print it's output to see the path to the documents directory of the app (This is a folder inside the path your looking for).

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Then you can use the URL however you need to.

`NSLog(@"%@", [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path]);`

If you really mean environment variable, there is another post containing a pretty exhaustive list of environment variables you can find here: [How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/canonical-list-of-xcode-environment-variables)

Comment: Yea, I've seen that link. I'm trying to open my core data .sqlite file in a SQLite Browser every time I run it on a simulator. I've got it working by just using a `*` for the application folder then using the $PROJECT_NAME.sql to find the right file. It works ok, but I'm really looking for a way to get the actual directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what's in the Environment, use the following code:

```
  NSDictionary *env = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
```