# How to build to a protected folder in xcode on 10.7

Tags: xcode, audiounit

im trying to build an audio unit synth and I've got it to compile but and it works so far but I want to debug it properly by setting my daw as a debug exexuble. The problem is that the daw only loads plugings that are in the component folder and xcode says it doesn't have permission to build there.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a build step to copy the plugin from the built products directory to your components folder. Aside from the fact that the internal built products directory is internal, the AU tools on Mac will *only* look for plugins in the system and user components directories, unlike VST which can be an arbitrary path.

The script would look something like this:

```
cp -r "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.component" "$HOME/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components"
```

Comment: it works!...Just out of curiousity where can I find more information as to why and how this works.

Comment: Nothing magic about it, it's just a 1 line bash shell script which uses some internal Xcode environment variables. Also of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6911421/14302