# Xcode - Run Post-Actions Script in Specific Build Configuration

Tags: xcode, macos, build

Is there a way to run a post-actions script in Xcode only if the project has been run in a particular build configuration (happens in Release, doesn't in Debug).

Much Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes; in your script the `$CONFIGURATION` variable will be set:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$CONFIGURATON" != "Release" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Does stuff only in Release build
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/canonical-list-of-xcode-environment-variables) to get a list of other Xcode variables that might interest you.