# Get current Scheme Name from Run Script Phase

Tags: xcode

Is there a way of grabbing the current scheme from a run script phase?

I've tried `$(SCHEME_NAME)` but it doesn't exist.

Comment: [not that I can see in the Xcode environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/canonical-list-of-xcode-environment-variables)

Comment: File an enhancement request at <http://bugreporter.apple.com>.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I couldn't find an environment variable to use, so I had to develop a work around: write a scheme name to disk in the *Build Pre-action* and then read it back out in the *Run Script* phase.

For each scheme you're interested in go to *Edit Scheme* and add a script with the following code:

```
rm -rf ${INTERMEDIATES_OUTPUT_DIR}
mkdir -p ${INTERMEDIATES_OUTPUT_DIR}
echo MY_SCHEME_NAME > ${SCHEME_FILE}
```

*[image: Build Pre-action]*

Next, go to your build target's "Build Settings" and add two "User-Defined Settings":

```
INTERMEDIATES_OUTPUT_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/build/intermediates/${CONFIGURATION}/
SCHEME_FILE=${INTERMEDIATES_OUTPUT_DIR}current_scheme.txt
```

Open up your "Run script" and add this:

```
SCHEME_NAME=`cat ${SCHEME_FILE}`
```

Be sure to add the intermediates build directory to your .gitignore file.

Obviously you could simplify this a bit by hardcoding a file name but this is a bit more robust (and we have other stuff that ends up in the intermediates directory, too).

Comment: EXCELLENT!!!

I'll have to point out that for the bash hackers like myself, my SCHEME_FILE path had spaces in it, so the line above should be SCHEME_NAME=`cat "${SCHEME_NAME}"`

... and those are backticks, not apostrophes!

This also aplies to the top, "${INTERMEDIATES_OUTPUT_DIR}" and "${SCHEME_FILE}"

Comment: @horseshoe7 I am getting this issue.. can you guys help me out
Showing All Issues
Error: Scheme 'SCHEME_NAME' does not exist in 'myproject.xcworkspace'.

Comment: uh, sorry, my comment should follow from the answer, but make sure you wrap ${SCHEME_FILE} in quotes so it will automatically escape the spaces in the pathname.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest one is set 'User Defined' variable as per scheme and use it.

Comment: Schemes and Configurations are different things and not always equal to each other

Answer (score 0):

You can write the scheme name to the `info.plist` file and read it back in Run Script Phase, in Edit Scheme menu, choose Build -> Pre-actions and add the following script:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :SchemeName \"$SCHEME_NAME\"" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

and then add the key `SchemeName` of type string in the `info.plist`, and its initial value is empty.

Finally, in the run script phase add the following:

```
SCHEME_NAME=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print SchemeName" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
```

Answer (score 0):

INTERMEDIATES_OUTPUT_DIR doesn't seem to work for building swift previews which I wanted customization on as well.  I ended up doing something similar using `defaults write` which I found works in all cases and doesn't involve the creation of a file.

Prebuild:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode LastBuildScheme "MySchemeName"`
```

Build Script:

```sh
[[ $(defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode LastBuildScheme) = "MySchemeName" ]] && echo "Scheme" || echo "Not Scheme"
```