# How can we retrieve current scheme from xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I wants to update the build number in plist file according to the scheme which is currently running in xcode project .
Ex: If i am running with Sandbox scheme my App version will be **{VERSION_NUM}S** and if I run with Production scheme App version wil be **{VERSION_NUM}P**.

So Can you please suggest me how can we retrieve Scheme

Answer (score 0):

How about change plist file with PlistBuddy at Edit Scheme->Build->Pre-actions?
[image]

Here is solution for edit plist in script ->
[Insert Subversion revision number in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372218/insert-subversion-revision-number-in-xcode)

My suggest is making script for each scheme.

By the way I found article for scheme name. -> [Get current Scheme Name from Run Script Phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776626/get-current-scheme-name-from-run-script-phase)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to get the name of the Scheme , Can you suggest me , I have already updated the plist file with Plistbuddy.

Comment: yes , But my requirement is to fully automate the scripts too , we should know which script to run right ? , that could be possible if we know scheme . do u have any idea