# How to convert Makefile into XCode compatible configuration?

Tags: xcode

I am moving away from simply using a Makefile and text editor. I would like to convert my Makefile so that I can use XCode properly. How can I convert this Makefile?

```
all:
    gcc engine.c $(MRUBY_HOME)/build/host/lib/libmruby.a -I $(MRUBY_HOME)/include $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is nothing stopping you from using a makefile in Xcode. just setup your target as an external build system and populate the "Build Tool" setting with the path to make (/usr/bin/make) and the "Directory" field pointing to the directory in your project containing the makefile. you can populate the "Arguments" field with any arguments needed for your makefile; these can be done with [Xcode variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/canonical-list-of-xcode-environment-variables) such as `$(ACTION)` (build, clean) and `$(CONFIGURATION)` (debug, release).

If you want to do away with the makefile completely then you will need to first add the source files and libraries to your target under the "build phases" tab for your build target. Any shell scripts can be added as a new "run script" build phase. other settings can be set from the "build settings" tab; specifically the "other c flags" field, although most compiler and linker settings should appear as options in that section.