# iOS inheritance of build phases in targets

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any way to inherit somehow Build Phases? For example I have the same shell script in each target. So I want to create parent target and define it there. Is it possible? How not to copy same script in each my target?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) ruby gem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072937/add-run-script-build-phase-to-xcode-project-from-podspec) answer says.
So you can just run the ruby script when you want to synchronize all the targets