# Variable for path to XCode's SharedPrecompiledHeaders folder

Tags: xcode, build, location, directory

During our iOS client build we run a clean to prevent/reduce failures. But last week all our build servers failed with this error

> fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'could not find file 'worspace/file_name.h' referenced by AST file'

It seemed that file_name.h was no longer required and a developer removed the svn external which brought it in. But the AST files still held a reference to it - despite the clean.

After investigating I found it was the files in the following folder

> var/folders/f3/bznwl6md2bx82f1fv_kkdzl00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders

Deleting SharedPrecompiledHeaders fixed the issue. At the time I manually did this.

But I'd like a way to automate it. Is there an environmental variable/alternative that can be used to find this directory? I noticed it varies between machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable you are looking for is SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR

Comment: Which is an xcode build setting. aka Precompiled Headers Cache Path

Answer (score 1):

The final solution was to place the shared precomps dir within the checkout. This allowed the build servers to completely clean the workspace between builds.

Achieved this by passing in the SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR to xcodebuild.

e.g.

xcodebuild -project *ProjectName* -target "*Target*" -configuration *Configuration* -sdk *SDKName* SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=*/absolute/path/to/checkout*

By passing this value in at the command line the SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR was set for all projects. i.e. Including Dependent Projects.

Answer (score 0):

Lane's answer is correct. If you need to retrieve this value from the command line parse the output of

xcodebuild -project *myProj.xcodeproj* -target "*myTarg*" -showBuildSettings

For further details see [How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)