# Swift classes in test project not visible in Objective-C XCTestCase class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xctest

I've created a `swift` class in my test project that targets such test project (and only it, it does not target the app project). I need to instantiate this `swift` class in a test method I wrote in an `Objective-C` `XCTestCase` class in this same test project, but I get an issue saying that it is an `Unknown receiver`. I successfully instantiate other `swift` classes I have in the app target by importing `MyAppTarget-Swift.h`, but I get an error if I add `#import "MyTestTarget-Swift.h"` (file not found). Anyway, the `swift` class I need to instantiate at this moment is in the test project itself, and the file targets the test project... why the `XCTestCase` class does not find that `swift` class? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932147/how-should-a-swift-objective-c-project-be-setup-for-unit-testing