# Test swift bridge file in objective-c test file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

How do I `import` a Swift file (which is in a test target only, it's a test helper) into an Objective-C test file? the Swift file is Objective-C compatible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932147/how-should-a-swift-objective-c-project-be-setup-for-unit-testing.

Comment: Possibly not :) ... that question is about involving app target, this is purely cross test/language dependencies within one test target. app code not involved