# xcode architectures macro for detecting arm64 or armv7

Tags: c++, xcode

My project uses a third party framework (with some .a libraries).

And unfortunately the .a libraries I got only support 32bit device.

So I can compiles and install the app on my ipod touch5 through xcode.

But, I can not compiles and install the app on my iphone6 which is arm64.

So I want to comment out the codes use the .a libraries when I compile arm64 using some kind of macro like:

```
#if (ARCHITECTURES == ARMV7 || ARCHITECTURES == ARMV7S)
    // only when bit32 device
    ThirdPartyManager::getInstance()->initSDK();
#endif
```

I tried to google but can not find any macro that I might be able to use ...

Any suggestion will be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be called ARCHS.

See this answer for more details about the more general question - how to get all build settings from the XCode:

[How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)