# Xcode build setting "Build Products Path" (CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR) is a lie?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

If I create a new application project, the build settings look something like this:

[image]

It claims to be using a build dir `build/Debug-iphoneos`. I assume this is relative to the project directory? In reality, the project is compiled to the "derived data" directory, under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CryptoTest2-abc...`

So what is going on here? Is this build setting simply ignored? What is the build setting that controls the output directory?

Answer (score 23):

This build setting is actually relative to the Derived Data setting.
You can change this setting if you go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations, and change the Derived Data directory setting to whatever suits your needs (Default, Relative or Custom).
[image: Xcode settings illustration]

You can also specify this on a per project-basis, if you specify an absolute path for that settings:

- You can either hardcode a path such as `/build/${CONFIGURATION}${EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME}`, then the project will be built into the folder build in the root folder.
- Or can you can choose to prepend the existing path with another environment variable. For example, to make the path relative to your project/workspace (As you would expect), you can prepend the original value with `${SRCROOT}/`, effectively creating a `build` folder at the root of your project/workspace.

Settings that can be substitued in `${<setting>}` are called **Build settings**, and are set automatically by Xcode/xcodebuild whenever you start building your project. Apple maintains a list of the available build settings here:
http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6

Comment: The link of the build settings reference is dead. Do you know where to find the current one? Thanks!

Comment: @Damnum just edited the post and fixed the link, Apple updated their doc

Comment: [Is there a way to make it per project and save that configuration in pbxproj files?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/43601115/how-to-make-deriveddata-or-build-location-in-xcode-to-be-relative-to-project)

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File** -> **Workspace Settings** -> **Advanced** and select **Legacy**

Comment: This is the correct answer. After select Legacy, you can set Build Products Path(in your own target's Build Settings) relative to you project directory.

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent full day trying to understand what am I doing wrong. Working with XCode is the most frastrating thing I ever done in my life