# Swift save files to project folder

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm writing a swift terminal program (let's say it's called "myProject") that requires me to save some files. I would like the files to be saved within the project folder programmatically.

I've seen [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project/12823466#12823466) there are some environment variables like $(PROJECT_DIR) that give the path to the project folder. I've already checked that XCode does have the $(PROJECT_DIR) variable using:

```
$ xcodebuild -project myProject.xcodeproj -target "myProject" -showBuildSettings
```

But I'm not exactly sure how I can use this variable in my actual code.
Like if I tried

```
print($(PROJECT_DIR))
```

I would just get the errors:

```
use of unresolved identifier '$' 
use of unresolved identifier 'PROJECT_DIR'
```

How do I get the path to my project folder programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't environment variables that are available to your program at runtime; they're used internally by Xcode for the build process.

Your program is located at `Bundle.main.executableURL` (`NSBundle.mainBundle().executableURL` in Swift 2) at runtime (`executablePath` is also available if you prefer).

If you have additional files that your program needs to access, they must be in a known location. You can use a standard directory in the filesystem such as /usr/local/bin, or you can create a bundle and copy those resources into the bundle as part of the build process.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But NSBundle.mainBundle().executableURL doesn't give me the path of the project folder that I wanted. It gives me:


"/Users/_____/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swiftclaw-ejedpqkbwdlfzbdmdfbmlwxroxft/Build/Products/Debug/myProject"


Instead I wanted:


"/Users/_____/Desktop/myProject


or wherever the location of the myProject.xcodeproj file is

Comment: Why does your compiled program need the directory where its source code is located?

Comment: There's a python script in the project folder that graphs the output of the files

Comment: You should put that script into a standard location like /usr/local/bin, then, and access it there. Even if you do get the project's directory into the executable, it will be baked-in; if the directory moves after you've compiled, this procedure will fail.

Comment: How will the project's directory be baked-in? It should change as the directory moves, which is why I'm looking for how to do it. Otherwise I would just type the path in manually.

Comment: The `$PROJECT_DIR` variable you're looking at doesn't exist past build time. There is no concept of a "project" or a "project directory" once your program is compiled.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clarifying that. Then I guess there is no way to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: No, you have to have to have a known location (even if it's only relative to something else, like the Documents directory, or your app's executable).