# xcodebuild manually building framework in run-script and follow same destination

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a framework that I need to build manually as a part of my run-script in xcode.

How can I copy the build setting from the current project when building it?

```
xcodebuild 
  -project "$PROJECT_DIR/myProject/MyProject.xcodeproj" 
  -scheme MyProject 
  -configuration "$MY_PROJECT_CONFIGURATION" 
  CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$APP_BUILD_DIR" 
  build
```

I'm specifically having problem matching `-destination`. Is there a way to get the -destination used to build the current project and pass it to xcodebuild

Answer (score 0):

Xcode offers this as a Environmental Variable:

```
build_dir=${BUILD_DIR} 
//use it 
... -destination $build_dir ...
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project) shows how to get all Environmental Variables.