# How to check the bitcode type of xx.Framework/xx.lib is `-fembed-bitcode` or `-fembed-bitcode-marker`

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcodebuild, bitcode

I use xcodebuild to build a framework, and I want to find a way to check the bitcode type is `-fembed-bitcode` or `-fembed-bitcode-marker`.

As you know, when bitcode type is `-fembed-bitcode`, the framework is full bitcode supported.

Answer (score 0):

[Use your `xcodebuild` command and add `-showBuildSettings` to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823466/981049).

Look at the results to see if you can find `-fembed-bitcode`, perhaps under `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to find a way to check the bitcode type of an existing framework developed by other people.