# Redirected Input thorough command line of .txt file into xcode(C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, input, command

I have a project in which I need to read a `.txt` file automatically through program arguments. I have tried typing `"< input.txt"` into the arguments tab but it does not seem to be reading it. I wrote a simple code to test this quicker and that still doesn't work. If  anyone else knows how to solve this problem that would be great, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r, c;
    cin >> r >> c;
    cout << r << " " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[photo of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lkFX.png)
  [

Answer (score 1):

It is enough complected task in Xcode 9. Suppose `input.txt` is the file that we need to pass to the standard input of our program like `prog < input.txt`.

The definitions of Xcode build environment variables are explained in [How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)

1. Open your project **Build Phases**. Press + there to add new **Run Script** task. Enter the command bellow. It expects `input.txt` is placed in the same directory where the program executable is built, see the value of `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` in the build log.

   ```
   echo "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME} < ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/input.txt" > ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}.sh
   ```

[image]
2. Add new scheme and edit it. For the **Run** task goto **Info** pane. Select **Terminal.app** in the **Executable** and uncheck **Debug executable**.

[image]

3. Goto **Arguments** pane. Press + and enter the command into the new argument

   ```
   ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}.sh
   ```

[image]

4. Finally build and run your application. New Terminal app must start and you must see like below there (it is from your code snipped)

[image]

Comment: So I can only do this from running xcode through the command line tool?

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but I followed all of these steps and the terminal opens on running but it doesn't display anything like yours.

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: It just says last login and my mabook name

Comment: You did something wrongly. Try to repeat all steps carefully.

Comment: Im just supposed to copy and paste exactly what you said correct?

Comment: I have followed these steps 100% and when I click to run the code all I get in terminal is...Last login: Sat Feb  3 11:59:40 on ttys347
MacBook:~ Mac$

Comment: Mostly yes, copy and paste is correct. The name of your input file supposed to be `input.txt` and the file must be placed in the same directory, there the executable is built.

Comment: yes i believe I did that, I added a photo, is that what you mean? Also it is input1.txt and i changed the name accordingly in your run script code/

Comment: Do not paste links to photos, it is prohibited here, your question will be downvoted. Please read my comments carefully, try to understand my pasted commands. `main.cpp` is not your compiled executable file in the built products directory, it is the source file in the project directory. Thus you placed `input1.txt` into a wrong place. Update the command in the **Run Script** or move your `input1.txt` into the correct place. I am going to stop further help here after this comment.

Comment: It didn't let me paste the photo, thats the only way I could show it, sorry. I moved the input.txt into the products folder but still no fix.

Comment: Compare the value of `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` in the build log with the base path of your `input1.txt`, your products dir. Or replace `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/input.txt` with the desired full path of `input1.txt`