# Does xcode use "xcodebuild" under the hood?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Does xcode use of the `xcodebuild` command behind the scenes to build?

If so, how can I find the exact `xcodebuild` command that is run?
I checked the report navigator but couldn't find it in there.

I would have thought that running `xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -project <myproject>.xcodeproj -scheme <myscheme>` would be identical to selecting `product -> build` in xcode (with a scheme/destination matching the command line), but they seem to have slightly different behavior.

For example, when running the command line above with the `-showBuildSettings` option, I noticed that `BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=NO` even though it should be set to `YES` according to the target's build settings. When running `product -> build` from xcode, the build settings logs (generated by following @Slipp D. Thompson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)) show `BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=YES`.

There are few other strange differences I noticed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One could do an experiment: move all `xcodebuild` binaries in some local folder and check that Xcode still able to build some application.

Since Apple [presents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) `xcodebuild` as a self contained command line tool for building Xcode projects, it is reasonable to suspect that use code sharing between both tools.