# Is there a way to access Xcodes current build output from a build phase run script?

Tags: xcode, build

I would like to know if it is possible to get the current build output from Xcode during a build phase (run script). (So access the current output mid build essentially)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xcodebuild -project myProj.xcodeproj -target "myTarg" -showBuildSettings
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823466/1180728

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the location where Xcode writes the logs isn’t written to until the build is complete. I need this info in flight as Xcodes is building. There is no reference to this location ( that I can see in the Env variables).