# Xcode: NATIVE_ARCHS vs NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL

Tags: xcode, macos, environment-variables

Looking in the page for [xcode settings](https://xcodebuildsettings.com/), I couldn't understand the intended difference between `NATIVE_ARCH` and `NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL`. Moreover, in some cases the values are different, as shown in the example from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/canonical-list-of-xcode-environment-variables):

`NATIVE_ARCH = armv7`

`NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL = x86_64`

From the documentation,

> [NATIVE_ARCH] Identifies the architecture on which the build is being
> performed

However I get armv7 when my Mac is an x86_64...
Which value should we trust?

**EDIT:** NATIVE_ARCH = armv7 when the architecture is set to arm64 (however my machine is still Intel...)